# jQuery UI $.datepicker.formatDate returns NaN NaN Nan

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a mySql table, in which there's a column called posted, that is set to type `timestamp` and defaults to `current_timestamp`. I then usen php PDO to get the value of it (along with a few other columns), and `echo json_encode` the whole thing. I call my .php file using an AJAX call, and now I want to format the date I receive.

Some googling resulted in me adding jQuery-UI for its `$.datepicker` function, as an easy way to format data. Since I'm probably going to be using some other jQuery-UI elements on my page, this seems like a reasonable solution. So far I've been unable to get it working though.

When I `console.log` the relevant object, I get this result `"2015-06-10 13:26:54"`.

Here's my JS code (you should be looking at var posted):

```
function makeArticleFeed(response) {
        $('#articles-feed').empty();
        if(response.length > 0) {
            for(var x = 0; x<response.length; x++) {
                console.log(response[x].posted);
                var posted = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd m yy', new Date(response[x].posted)); 
                $("#articles-feed").append(
                    '<div class="article-box"><h1><a href="#">'+response[x].title+
                    '</a></h1><h3><a href="#">' +response[x].author_id+
                    '</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;'+ posted+
                    '</h3><p>'+response[x].extract+'</p></div>'
                    );
            } //end article feed for loop
        } 
        else {
            $("#articles-feed").append('<h1>Sorry, no article found!</h1>');
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what you get when you pass the string `Invalid Date` to the `formatDate()` function.

In other words, `response[x].posted` is not a valid date that can be parsed by javascripts `new Date`.

If it's a timestamp from MySQL, it's generally in the format `2015-06-11 16:48:24` and you can get epoch time in most serverside languanges, for instance just passing it to PHP's `strtotime` would work, and then you'd have seconds from epoch, and javascript accepts milliseconds so you'd multiply by a thousand either on the server or before passing it to `new Date`.

Comment: so I guess I should be formatting the date with php before sending it out as encoded json? Or is there a way to do this using jQuery/Javascript (I don't know a lot about coding php)